# Android ReceyclerView GridLayoutManager scroll a set number of items at a time

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I have a **RecyclerView** with a **GridLayoutManager** as its LayoutManager. What I want to do is that whenever the user scrolls the rv, instead of following the position of finger, the rv should automatically scroll to the (current+16)th position. In this way I want the rv to scroll a whole "*page*" at once.

Essentially, what I want is to **override the scrolling behavior of RecyclerView**.

At first I thought I needed to do something with the GridLayoutManager but I couldnt find a method that disables the default scrolling or an interface that lets me catch all the scroll events myself.

I also was unable to find a definitive answer by searching around on stackoverflow and other online resources.

Is this even possible?

---

EDIT. Here is the code I have tried till now:

I tried to listen to the newState value hoping that it would be related to position of some individual item in the rv but it only gives SCROLL_STATE_IDLE, SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING or SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING.

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            Log.d(TAG, ""+newState);
        }
});
```

On probing the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.OnScrollListener.html), I found the onScrolled() method, but have no idea how I would go about disabling the default scroll so that I can catch this event and scroll the rv myself using:

```
    mLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(mPosition);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code and any errors you ran into, so we can help you better.

Comment: Hey @RubenSteins, thanks for your comment. I have added whatever I was able to figure out in the docs till now. I haven't actually been able to write much code because I am just perplexed as to how I need to approach this problem.